# ¿como esperar a que un elemento este visible? selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium

como puedo esperar a que un div sea visible? he investigado en la documentacion oficial de selenium y usan la funcion `Until(ExpectedCondition.ElementExists(By.TagName("div")))` pero en mi proyecto yo no tengo la clase ExpectedCondition, como puedo hacer la espera???

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
protected IWebElement WaitUntilElementIsShown(IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        try
        {
            
            WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
                           //No encuentra la clase ExpectedCondition
            return w.Until(ExpectedCondition.ElementExists(By.TagName("div")));
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

He intentado de esta manera, pero me lanza excepciones de vez en cuando.

```
public static bool WaitUntilIsShown(IWebDriver driver, By element)
    {
        try
        {
            WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Const.TIMEOUTSECONDS));
            return w.Until((d) => d.FindElement(element).Displayed == true);
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de la web, porque de lo contrario no hay como validar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución debería funcionar:

```
public bool WaitUntilElementExists(By elementLocator, int timeout = 10)
{
   try
   {
      var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, timeout));
      return wait.Until(condition =>
      {
         try
         {
            var elementToBeDisplayed = Driver.FindElement(elementLocator);
            return elementToBeDisplayed.Displayed;
         }
         catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
         {
            return false;
         }
         catch (NoSuchElementException)
         {
            return false;
         }
      });
   }
   catch (NoSuchElementException)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```